# Optimization of a list in Excel with Variables

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of 153 golfers with associated salaries and average scores.

I want to find the combination of 6 golfers that optimizes avg score and keeps salary under $50,000.

I've tried using Solver, but I am stuck!  Can anyone help please?  :)

Comment: That optimizes the sum of the average score*

Comment: Filter for salaries < $50,000, sort by average score descending (so highest is on top) and then the first 6 are what you're looking for.

Comment: @tigeravatar I think Op wants the total sum of the salaries under 50,000 not the individual.  But I have been off today on my understanding so yours may be correct.

Comment: Unless golfers just do not get paid well at all, $50,000 total salary spread among 6 people? That's an average of $8333.33 per person which is way under minimum wage O.o

Comment: @ScottCraner, correct.  There's a list of golfers where salary ranges from 12,500 - 5,000.  Each golfer also has average points per tournament

I want to find the combination of six golfers that maximizes the sum of the six golfers average while keeping their cumulative salary under the 50,000 cap

Comment: As a note, the number of combinations of 6 golfers from a pool of 153 is `16,133,132,940`  Note that yes, that is over 16 *billion* combinations.  Even if Solver can do it, it will probably crash Excel.

Comment: @tigeravatar you're right.  maybe another program like matlab or something would do the trick.  just have to figure out how to write the math!

Comment: @tigeravatar I don't see why Excel would crash on a simple model like this, In fact I tried it with some random data for 153 players and Excel solves it just fine. Note that it will use a MIP solver that is smarter than just evaluating all possible combinations,

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I am personally not very familiar with the Excel Solver add-in so unfortunately I am unable to provide a working solution.  If you have a solution that the OP can implement, you should post it as an answer so the OP can test it and select your answer for future users who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrating a solution that is pretty close to what @ErwinKalvelagen suggested.

1. Column A is the names of the 153 golfers
2. Column B is the golfers salaries (generated by `=RANDBETWEEN(50, 125)*100`, filled down, then Copy/Paste Values)
3. Column C is the golfers average scores (generated by `=RANDBETWEEN(70, 85)`, filled down, then Copy/Paste Values)
4. Column D is a 0 or 1 to indicate if the golfer is included.
5. Cell `F2` is the total salary, given by `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B154,D2:D154)`
6. Cell `G2` is the number of golfers, given by `=SUM(D2:D154)`
7. Cell `H2` is the average score of the team, given by `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C154,D2:D154)/G2`

The page looks like this, before setting up Solver ...

[image]

The Solver setup looks like this ...

[image]

According to the help, it says to use Evolutionary engine for non-smooth problems. In Options, I needed to increase the Maximum Time without improvement from 30 to 300 (60 may have been good enough).

[image]

It took a couple of minutes for it to complete. It reached the solution of 70 fairly quickly, but spent more time looking for a better answer.

[image]

And here are the six golfers it came up with.

[image]

Of the golfers with an average of 70, it could have found a lower salary.

[image]

In Cell `I2` added the formula `=F2+F2*(H2-70)` which is essentially salary penalized by increases in average score above 70 ...

[image]

... and use the same Solver setup, except to minimize Cell `I2` instead of `H2` ...

[image]

and these are the golfers it chose ...

[image]

Again - it looks like there is still a better solution. It could have picked Name97 instead of Name96.

Comment: The built-in version of Solver reports, "This problem is too large for Solver to handle."  To get around this, you could buy the full version of Solver and use that.  However, in this problem, the objective and constraints are all linear functions of the 0-1 decision variables.  This means that, an alternative is the free OpenSolver add-in (see opensolver.org), which has no artificial limitations on the size of the problem (but can only solve linear problems).  In my case, it solved the original problem above in a few seconds with an average score of 85.

Comment: Why did you set solver to "min" $h$2 instead of "max" $h$2?

Comment: H2 is the average score. In golf, a lower score is better - unless there's some other criteria I missed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple optimization problem that can be solved using Excel solver (just use "Simplex Lp solver" -- somewhat of a misnomer as we will use it here to solve an integer programming or MIP problem).

You need one column with 153 binary (BIN) variables (Excels limit is I believe 200). Make sure you add a constraint to set the values to Binary. Lets call this column INCLUDE; Solver will fill it with 0 or 1 values. Sum these values, and add a constraint with SUMINCLUDE=6. Then add a column with INCLUDE * SCORE. Sum this column and this is your objective (optimizing the average is the same as optimizing the sum). Then add a column with INCLUDE*SALARY and sum these. Add a constraint with SUMSALARY <= 50k. Press solve and done.

I don't agree with claims that Excel will crash on this or that this does not fit within the limits of Excels solver. (I really tried this out).

I prefer the simplex method above the evolutionary solver as the simplex solver is more suitable for this problem: it is faster (simplex takes < 1 seconds) and provides optimal solutions (evolutionary solver gives often suboptimal solutions).

If you want to solve this problem with Matlab a function to look at is `intlinprog` (Optimization Toolbox).

To be complete: this is the mathematical model we are solving here:

[image]

Results with random data:

[image]

....

[image]

Comment: I set up the equation the way you said and it returns an error that says:

"Solver can not find a point for which all constraints are satisfied."

It optimizes for score and six golfers, but does not do so within the Salary constraints.  (note:  i do have constraint SUM of Salary set to <= 50000)

@erwin kalvelagen

Comment: It is also possible your data is "wrong" and there is no feasible solution to your problem. Make sure the 6 cheapest players are within the budget,